# Connecting applet to database with mysql-connector and adding external jar to applet

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, applet

I am having trouble with connecting my applet to the database which is on the same server as the applet. It seem that the problem is that it can't find the com.mysql.jdbc.driver everytime i run the applet from the html it gives a classnotfound exception: com.mysql.jdbc.driver. Code in the applet looks as follows:

```
class Connect {
    private Connection con;
    private Statement st;
    private ResultSet rs;


    public Connect (){

        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ghghghg:3306/Roombooking", "root", "ghghgh?");
            st= con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("Connection established");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(login, "IT WORKS!!");
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("Error:" + ex);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(login, ex);

        }
    }
```

I have tried adding the mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar to the same folder as the applet on my server. Also using the:

```
archive="mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar"
```

When i do that and also when i add the mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar to the same folder as the applet it throws another exception: ExceptionInInitializer.

everything works when run by eclipse.

Can anyone help me i'm feeling completely stuck :(

Comment: Put the absolute address of the .jar file.

Comment: `ExceptionInInitializer`  Post the entire stack trace.  Note that an applet should not be *allowed* to have direct access to the DB.  If it does, so do hackers.

Answer (score 0):

**Signed Your** "mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar" jar and replace it to your original jar.

Also Locate them explicitly in your applet tag. Like Below

**app.archive = '/esense/resources/lib/Applet.jar, /esense/resources/lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.30.jar;**

Hope this ll work.